What decides our next birth - Ishvara(God) or Law of Karma?
Namasthe.
I wanted to clarify who and what decides our next birth?
I am aware that next birth is decided based on 3 parameters

Karma
Samskāras
Last thought at time of death

Regarding next birth, Krishna has said in Bhagavad Gita Chapter 16, verses 19-20

Bhagavad Gita: Chapter 16, Verse 19-20
तानहं द्विषत: क्रूरान्संसारेषु नराधमान् |  क्षिपाम्यजस्रमशुभानासुरीष्वेव योनिषु ||
19|| आसुरीं योनिमापन्ना मूढा  जन्मनि जन्मनि | मामप्राप्यैव कौन्तेय ततो
यान्त्यधमां गतिम् || 20||
These cruel and hateful persons, the vile and vicious of humankind, I
constantly hurl into the wombs of those  with similar demoniac natures
in the cycle of rebirth in the material  world. These ignorant souls
take birth again and again in demoniac  wombs. Failing to reach Me, O
Arjun, they gradually sink to the most  abominable type of existence.

Here, Krishna says I decide the next birth of demonic people. From that Can we infer that Krishna(or Ishvara) decides our next birth?
Also, in Srimad Bhagavatham, its mentioned next birth (punarjanma) takes place under the supervision of the Supreme Lord

ŚB 3.31.1
श्रीभगवानुवाच कर्मणा दैवनेत्रेण जन्तुर्देहोपपत्तये । स्त्रिया:
प्रविष्ट उदरं पुंसो रेत:कणाश्रय: ॥ १ ॥
The Personality of Godhead said: Under the supervision of the Supreme
Lord and according to the result of his work, the living entity, the
soul, is made to enter into the womb of a woman through the particle
of male semen to assume a particular type of body.

But in Svetāsvatara upanishad [6.11] says God is the Witness [sākṣī], its also mentioned in BG 9.18 And as per Yoga Sutras of Patanjali- Quora Law of Karma is responsible . As per BG 16.19 and SB 3.31.1 slokas mentioned above, can we infer even though God does not have the complete hand in deciding next birth (punarjanma) can we infer that the process of next birth happens under supervision of God (evident from SB 3.31.1 and BG 16.19)
Also Ramana Maharshi has mentioned same in God, the scriptwriter that,

The Ordainer controls the fate of souls in accordance with their past
deeds – their prarabdha karma. Whatever is destined not to happen will
not happen, try hard how you may. Whatever is destined to happen will
happen, do what you may to stop it. This is certain. The best course,
therefore, is for one to be silent.

How does Iswara, ‘the ordainer’, allocate destiny and decide next birth? Here is Bhagavan explaining the process, using an interesting and novel analogy:

A man might have performed many karmas in his previous births. A few
of them alone will be chosen for this birth and he will have to enjoy
the fruits in this birth. It is something like a slide show where the
projectionist picks a few slides to be exhibited at a performance, the
remaining slides being reserved for another performance. (The Mountain
Path 1982, p. 23)

And here is a second quote on how this process works:

Individuals have to suffer their karmas but Iswara manages to make the
best of their karmas for his purpose. God manipulates the fruits of
karma but he does not add or take away from it. The subconscious of
man is a warehouse of good and bad karma. Iswara chooses from this
warehouse what he sees will best suit the spiritual evolution … of
each man, whether pleasant or painful. Thus, there is nothing
arbitrary. (Conscious Immortality, 1st ed. p. 376)

So based on BG 16.19, SB 3.31.1 and teachings of Jivan-Mukta Shri Ramana Maharshi, could it be possible that Along with law of karma Ishvara(God) has some role in deciding our next birth and our prarabdha based on our Sanchita karma, sanskaras and state of consciousness at time of death ??

Question:
So based on BG 16.19, SB 3.31.1 and teachings of Jivan-Mukta Shri Ramana Maharshi, could it be possible that Along with law of karma Ishvara(God) has some role in deciding our next birth and our prarabdha based on our Sanchita karma, sanskaras and state of consciousness at time of death ??
Answer:
Isvara has a role in deciding the next birth since He has to distribute the fruits of Karma. Our karma does not have a direct role in deciding our next birth. (Here Vedanta differs from the views of Buddhists and Jains who claim that the law of Karma can alone decide our birth.)
Let us take a look at the two Brahma Sutra verses given below to understand the situation.

The fruit of action is from Him, this being the logical position.

Brahma Sutra III.ii.38

But Badarayana considers the earlier One (viz God) (as bestower of
results), because He is mentioned as the cause even of action.

Brahma Sutra III.ii.41

But the teacher Badarayana considers the earlier One, i.e., God
Himself, as the bestower of results. The word "but" refutes the views
that the result is obtained from either from the action itself or the
unseen potency of action. The accepted conclusion is that the result
comes from God, be it either by taking into account the action
itself or the unseen potency, as it may.
Why?
"Because He is mentioned as the cause". For God is presented as the
cause both by way of making others act virtuously or viciously and of
bestowing the results, in the text, "It is He Himself who makes him do
a good deed when He wishes to raise up from the worlds; and it is He
Himself who makes him do a bad deed whom He wishes to throw down
(Kausitaki Upanishad III.8). This fact is mentioned in the Gita as
well, "Whichever divine form a devotee wants to worship with faith, I
ordain for him unswerving faith in that very form. Endowed with that
faith, he continues in the worship of that very form, and obtains from
it the results he desires, as ordained by Me" (Gita VII.21-22). In all
the Upanishads creations are declared as acts of God. And God's
bestowing of results consists precisely in His creating the creatures
according to individual merits. The defects of the impossibility of
the emergence of variegated results from the very same cause, and so
on, do not arise since God acts by taking into account the efforts
made by the creatures.

Brahma Sutra Bhasya of Sri Sankaracharya III.ii.41

so,  karmas those will be prarabdha, depends on Ishwar’s will?

@PradipGangopadhyay Krishna says In BG 5.14, he does not give fruits of action . https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/5/verse/14

No that is not what it says. 'In regard to all beings in this world, the sovereign soul is not the cause of the sense of agency, nor of actions, nor of the fruition of actions. It is Nature that does all this.' Gita 5.14. It is saying that our body-mind complex does the work and our Atman remains as an witness.

Sir , in BG 9.9 Krishna says he is just a witness and neutral observer and has no role to play and everything taken care by Law of Karma. This clearly contradicts this statement from Brahma Sutra that Ishvara gives the fruits of karma .

I) Your first question I wanted to clarify who and what decides our next birth? I am aware that next birth is decided based on 3 parameters, 1) Karma 2) Samskāras
and 3) Last thought at time of death.
Your claim of punarjanma based on 3 factors are absolutely fallacious!
All the three factors are one and the same. First factor Karma is vedantic parlance, second factor Samskāras is yoga terminology and final factor Last thought at time of death is from Bhagavath Gita. These three factors are various angle through which the same truth (punarjanma/reincarnation) is perceived!
II) Your second question Regarding next birth, Krishna has said in Bhagavad Gita Chapter 16, verses 19-20........Here, Krishna says I decide the next birth of demonic people. From that Can we infer that Krishna(or Ishvara) decides our next birth?
If Krishna decides the next birth of every soul, then what is difference between Hinduism and Abrahamic religions(Judaism, Christianity, and Islam)? i.e. Krishna is prejudiced tantamount to Abrahamic Gods!
Isvara and Karma are different angles of perceiving the same truth. If you express punarjanma in terms of Law of Karma or in terms of Bhagavan Krishna, both are one and the same! That means Lord Krishna(or Isvara) always works through Law of Karma and never indiscriminately.
The interpretation of sloka is that Krishna decides but only through law of karma.
III) Your third question Also, in Srimad Bhagavatham, its mentioned next birth (punarjanma) takes place under the supervision of the Supreme Lord
........can we infer that the process of next birth happens under supervision of God (evident from SB 3.31.1 and BG 16.19)
Both Svetāsvatara upanishad [6.11] and BG [9.18] says God is Witness [Sākṣī]. Look at the Phrase of SB [3.31.1] "Under the supervision of the Supreme Lord" means God supervises punarjana. The next phrase "according to the result of his work" means Sanchita Karma of the Jiva. One angle is that as God is Witness, so Karma alone takes care of punarjana. The other angle is God is not only Witness  but also supervises punarjana through Karma. Observe that both angles are one and the same!
IV) Your fourth question Also Ramana Maharshi has mentioned same............How does Iswara, ‘the ordainer’, allocate destiny and decide next birth?
As this excerpts does not talk about punarjanma, there is no contradiction here.
V) Your fifth and final question Here is Bhagavan explaining the process, using an interesting and novel analogy............could it be possible that Along with law of karma Ishvara(God) has some role in deciding our next birth and our prarabdha based on our Sanchita karma, sanskaras and state of consciousness at time of death ?
Observe this statement "God manipulates the fruits of karma but he does not add or take away from it" which means that God works through Karma without disturbing it!
Since your question contains all three factors along with God, let us analyze one by one:

At the time of death, the subset of Sanchita Karma which are ripe
and ready to sprout, will decide the suitable embodiment to
experience and a life-span. This sebset is known as prarabdha karma.
In Yoga parlance, a subset of samskaras stored in Kārana Sarīra,
which are ripe and ready to sprout is called known as  Karmāsaya (कर्माशय/Latent Impressions of Action) responsible for Punarjanma (पुनर्जन्म/Reincarnation) by deciding embodiment and life-span.
Bhagavān Krishna says in Bhagavath Geetha [8.6] about taking future
birth that depends upon your thought at the time of death. If one
thinks about a bird at the time of death, then he will assume a bird
form in the forthcoming birth [Refer my Quora Post on Jada
Bharatha(जडभरत)]. If you utter ‘Govinda’ at the moment of
death, you will reach the Padāravinda(पदारविन्द/Lotus Feet) of Lod
Krishna!

With reference to answer question (I), any claim of punarjanma based on 3 factors are absolutely fallacious because all the the three factors are one and the same. First factor Karma is vedantic parlance, second factor Samskāras is yoga terminology and final factor Last thought at time of death is from Bhagavath Gita. These three factors are various angle through which the same truth (punarjanma/reincarnation) is perceived!
The question is "Along with law of karma Does Ishvara(God) has some role in deciding our next birth?"
The right statement is Ishvara(God) decides punarjanama through Law of Karma or Samskāras or Last thought at time of death.
VI) Your title question What decides our next birth - Ishvara(God) or Law of Karma?

Law of Karma decides our punarjanma.
Ishvara(God) decides our punarjanma through Law of Karma.

Both statements are different angles of perceiving the same truth(punarjanma). If you express punarjanma in terms of Law of Karma or in terms of Ishvara, both are one and the same! That means Ishvara always works through Law of Karma and never Indiscriminately!
The above two statements are one and the same. In both the cases, Ishvara is Witness invariably.
Good Luck!

I sincerely request if you can please answer this one last question sir . Will be very greatful thanks . It's very important and worried about it https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/61460/does-self-imposed-conditional-promises-affect

@Kathik, I am busy on something else. Please give me more little time. I will be back. Thanks.

Brahma-Sutra 3.2.38: Sanskrit text and English translation.
फलमतः, उपपत्तेः ॥ ३८ ॥
phalamataḥ, upapatteḥ || 38 ||

From Him (the Lord) are the fruits of actions ; for that is reasonable. Source :- https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras/d/doc74952.html As per this fruits of karma are given by Ishvara. But this directly contradicts BG 9.9 where Krishna is mentioned as neutral observer and BG 9.18 where they mention krishna as just a witness


You said Yajnavalkya created this law of karma. What happened to that?

I have commented in the same post sir . Please have a look .

O.K. Thanks.....
