Does Self imposed conditional promises affect?
NOTE:-
This question is similar but not a duplicate. It's a different question Please Kindly don't ignore and please answer it. One more thing I am an OCD patient. My question may appear silly stupid or absurd I sincerely request you people to pls don't judge me and kindly answer my question
As I said I am an OCD patient . Due to my health issues I keep putting 100s of promises to God and have broken these promises such that

If I eat junk food for next 2 years, my father will never get
human life for eternity even after crores of Kalpas
If I break vow of celibacy, my mother will spiritually perish and rot in lower realms forever
If I don't do 1008 Naam jap today, my father will be born as animals or
birds for eternity and rot in lower realms and suffer Durgati

These are some of them . Similarly I have put lots of promises and broken them
My main question is,
So now both are laws

Law 1:-(God's Law about breaking promise)
God has created a law that if u break a promise with condition ,that
will happen . If there is no such law, let us assume for this question that there is the law.
So as per this law because I have broken them, my father or mother is
supposed to rot in lower Yonis for eternity and never get human life
even after crores of Kalpas.

And,

Law 2:- Law of Karma Also there is the Law of Karma where everything works based on the karma and we only get what we deserve
based on our own past karmas . As per law of karma , my father or
mother gets next life based on their karmas (not necessarily that they
never get human life for eternity)

Suppose if my father or mother has done reasonable punya karma in their life and not done such HUGE PAAP in this or any of the past lives in sanchita account so as to never get human life, or to become animals birds for eternity, will breaking these promises affect them ?
Here, both the laws are contradictory in its outcome.
Because as Per god's Law if we break promise it should affect them. Even if there may not be a god's law please let us assume for it  for this scenario
And at same time as per Laws of karma if they don't deserve it such a huge punishment, will it affect them now?
Please kindly carefully read my question and please answer me . It will be a great help
Thank you

Answer is No.
Suppose you write an entrance exam making a promise (self-imposed) that if I fail, then my close friend X will go to hell. This promise makes no sense because your friend X is in no way related (knowingly or unknowingly) as far as exam results are concerned. Even if you fail exams, your friend will never go to hell on account of your promise!
Similarly if you pledge your parents (knowingly or unknowingly) involving in your self-imposed promises, then they will never be affected whether you are  successful in your attempts or not.
I) Vishnu Puranam [Book-2, Ch-6, sloka-25] says the following:
The violator of a vow, and one who breaks the rules of his order,
falls into the Sandansa (or hell of pincers).

- Vishnu Puranam: Book-2, Ch-6, sloka-25.

Vishnu Puranam asserts that the break of a vow only affects the violator and nobody else.
Beware-1: Vishnu Puranam's verdict is applicable to vows pledged against a 3rd person directly, but not for self-imposed promises (where no third person is involved).
II) Padma Purana [Brahma-Kānda, chapter-26, slokas: 1-42] talks about the Importance of Keeping Promise. It is conversation between Rishi Sūta and Rishi Śaunaka. Rishi Sūta says what would happen if a promise offered using one's right hand is not kept up:
1. He goes to a terrible hell. 
2. His dead ancestors are tormented in hell

Beware-2: Like Vishnu Puranam, Padma Purana's verdict too is applicable to vows pledged against a 3rd person directly, but not for self-imposed promises (where no third person is involved).
Vishnu puranam asserts that only violator is affected and goes to hell but no body else whereas Padma puranam says that not only violator but also his ancestors are affected.
When both puranas pronounce conflicting verdicts, then how should it be reconciled?
Since puranas have equal priority, consultation with higher authority is needed in order to resolve. The higher authority to puranas are (1) Vedas and (2) Itihāsas, in that order. Please read my Quora post to know about the precedence and authority among Veda, Itihāsa and Purāna.
From the above Quora post, it it crystal clear that Itihasa has higher priority than purana in resolving conflicts arising among puranas on a specific topic.
Beware-3: Vedas possesses the highest precedence and authority over Itihāsās and Purānās.
Let us recall a break of promise took place in one of the Itihāsās called Mahābhāratam [Adhi Parva Ch-8] involving Drona and Drupada.

In Mahābhāratam, Drupada and Drona were classmates
who were so close and Drupada promised he would give half of the
kingdom when he would become king. Drona was too poor to feed even his
son, so he approached Drupada asking for a cow instead of half-kingdom
but Drupada not only refused him but also insulted him. Unhappy Drona
taught the Astra Vidya to Pandavas and subsequently, on the
instructions of Drona, Arjuna defeated Drupada in the battle and
brought him before Drona. However, Drona demonstrated his magnanimity
and forgave him!
-Mahābhāratam: Adhi Parva Ch-8.

Bear in mind, Drupada was punished in the same birth for the breach of promise and Mahabharata had never mentioned about his father(King Prishata) or ancestors being suffered in hell or reached Adhogati because of a broken promise!
The words of Vishnu purana and Padma Purana can be safely set side quoting the incident of Drona-Drupada took place in the Mahābhāratam(an Itihāsā) which has higher precedence over puranas.
III) Your first question Law 1:-(God's Law about breaking promise)
This has been already settled, refer point (II) above.
IV) Your second question Law 2:- Law of Karma
Since Itihāsā has precedence over puranas, from Drona-Drupada story, it is understood that Drupada's broken promise never affected his parents nor his ancestors.
So, your parent's Āgāmikarma(आगामिकर्म/being made or currently getting accumulated)
are unaffected because of your self-imposed broken promises.

V) Your third and final question Because as Per god's Law if we break promise..........will it affect them now?
Please refer answers (III) and (IV) above.
Good Luck!

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

NO. Self imposed promises are psychological. Our brain sets milestones to achieve our goals. These are like To-do-lists or planners to finish small tasks to achieve final task/project. Such promises and goal setting are normal. Our vedic calendar is based on our seasons/harvests/food/health/community,  so we should do fasting, pooja, celebrate festivals , consume food acordingly. Our promises should be based on adhering the shastra imposed karmas. Random self imposed promises may be fruitless.
"Knowledge is superior. Meditation is superior to knowledge. Greater than meditation, is renunciation of the results of karma/actions. Through renunciation, one attains tranquility/calmness" - B.G 12.12
B.G. 12.12
Krishna advises one to forego results of our (sincere dedicated) actions or effort, for our self-development or service to others. If suppose the results are not what one expected, there will not be anger, sadness, regret.
By expecting high rewards for cheap stakes/short-cuts/promises - puja/fasting on random days, hundi-donations, physical suffering/1000 push-ups are like bribing Krishna. These are random acts/promises that do not count for 'Sincere Effort'.
Find the real cause of your problems, create plans/self-control routines (health,exercise,doing real chores) and make sincere effort to find solutions and resolve them. Then, start following the right living.
First, replace word like 'promise' to Tasks/Practice/Resolution, then you can set mind to have flexible schedule or alternative methods, incase of any issues. Adhere to your goal, but be flexible to adjust. Else rigidity creates OCD. Also, don't assume anyone (yourself or parents etc.) suffer punishments for your self made routines/failures, that is  'cognitive dissonance' . If you fail in your goals, find the causes and adjust to different methods/options.
Important aspect of success is 'Stamina'. Strength/Will is for starting the task, Stamina is for Finishing a task. Only practice, habit, adding small taks and sustaining for long time will help with stamina.
